# Updated: How to reduce QWidget nesting in PyQt code?

Tags: python, pyqt5

## Updated Question

I think my original quandary might be a result of the structure of my PyQt app. The way I've approached creating a GUI is to divide the larger widget into smaller pieces, each given their own class until the parts are simple enough. Because of this, I end up with a ton of nesting, as a large widget holds instances of smaller widgets, and those hold their own even smaller widgets. It makes it hard to navigate data around the app.

*How should a PyQt app be structured so that it is simple to understand in code and yet has a structure containing very little nesting?* I haven't found many examples of this around, so I'm sort of stuck. The code example in my original question shows a pretty good example of the structure I'm currently using, which has a large amount of nesting.

### Info on program

The GUI is used to create a set of parameters for running a test. The options in each setting should correspond to a binary number, and all of the binary numbers indicated by each set of options are collected, formed into a single sequence of binary numbers, and passed on. Changes to settings do not have to be carried over between sessions, as each new session will most likely correspond to a new test (and thus a new set of choices for settings).

The basic flow of the app should be that upon opening it, all available settings (about 20 total) are set to their default values. A user can go through and change whatever settings they would like, and once they're done they can press a "Generate" button to gather all of the binary numbers corresponding to the settings and create the command. It would be very helpful to have a live preview of individual bits that updates as settings are changed, which is why updates must be immediate.

Some settings are dependent on other; for instance, Setting A has 4 options, and if option 3 is selected, Setting B should be made visible, otherwise it is invisible.

## Original Question

I'm definitely a beginner to PyQt, so I don't quite know if I've worded my question correctly, but here goes. I've got a GUI wherein I'm attempting to take a bunch of different settings, keep track of what number was selected from each setting, and then pass the number up to an object that keeps track of all of the numbers from all of the settings. The trouble is that I don't know the best way to get all the individual settings values up my tree of classes, so to speak. Here's the structure of my GUI so far:

- **Bottom**: individual custom QWidgets, each responsible for a single setting. Each has a signal that fires whenever the value it returns changes.
- **Middle**: a QWidget containing ~7-10 individual settings each. These collect settings into related groups.
- **Top**: a QTabWidget that places each instance of a setting group into an individual tab. This widget also contains an object that should ideally collect all of the settings from individual groups into it.

*My question is how do I get the values from the bottom layer signals to the top layer widget?* My only idea is to connect all of the signals from those small setting widgets to a signal in the middle layer, and connect the middle layer signal to something in the top layer. This sort of chaining seems crazy, though.

I'm running PyQt5 and Python 3.7.

Here's some stripped down code which hopefully shows what I want to do.

```py
class TabWindow(QTabWidget):
   def __init__(self):
       super().__init__()
       self.tabs = [SettingsGroup1, SettingsGroup2, SettingsGroup3]
       self.setting_storage = {  # dictionary is where I'd like to store all settings values
           # 'setting name': setting value
       }
       for tab in self.tabs:
           self.addTab(tab, 'Example')


class SettingsGroup(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # not shown: layout created for widget
        self.settings = []

    def add_to_group(self, new_setting):
        self.settings.append(new_setting)
        # not shown: add setting to the layout


class SettingsGroup1(SettingsGroup):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.add_to_group([Setting1, Setting2, Setting3])

class SettingsGroup2(SettingsGroup):...

class SettingsGroup3(SettingsGroup):...


class Setting(QWidget):
    val_signal = pyqtSignal([int], name='valChanged')

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.val = None
        self.name = name


    def set_val(self, new_val):
        self.val = new_val
        self.val_signal.emit(self.val) # <-- the signal I want to pass up


class Setting1(Setting):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__(name)
        # not shown: create custom setting layout/interface

class Setting2(Setting):...

class Setting3(Setting):...
```

I use a lot of inheritance (SettingsGroup -> SettingsGroup1, 2, 3) because each subclass will have its own functions and internal dependencies that are unique to it. For each Setting subclass, for instance, there is a different user interface.

Thanks for any help provided!

Comment: Why don't you connect the signal to that top widget's slot?

Comment: @ipaleka could you clarify where in the code you'd suggest that connection be made?

Comment: Maybe after that `addTab` call, like `for widget in tab.settings: widget.val_signal.connect(...)`.

Comment: Yeah, that would probably work. Wish it could be a bit more elegant than digging down through everything to get to the individual widgets, but I guess that's what's gotta happen for each widget to do something in TabWindow. I can use it for now. Thanks!

Comment: When it's about PyQt I can't say what *elegant* means. Honestly. I suppose that your initial suggestion that you call "crazy" is an elegant solution from Qt point of view.

Comment: [The Zen](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/#the-zen-of-python) says: *Flat is better than nested*.

Comment: @ekhumoro I'm definitely open to the possibility that my structuring is bad. Could you elaborate on how to flatten this out? I'm a PyQt beginner, so I'm not sure. It seems really difficult to keep the code organized without dividing the GUI into 'sub-widgets', so to speak.

Comment: I've edited my question to better reflect the issue of PyQt app structure and nesting.

Comment: @nmpauls Is it necessary to notify the top widget every time there is a change in any of the bottom widgets? I see that setting_storage is a dictionary. What is the key and value of each item? On the other hand, the design depends on what you want to do

Comment: @eyllanesc It is necessary to notify the top widget with each change to any bottom widget. The overall goal is to keep the data stored in the top widget in sync with whatever the values in the bottom widgets are. That is a good point of clarification: the dictionary (or similar data storage) would have the name of a setting as its key and the setting's current selection as its value. Each bottom level setting widget has a unique name attribute to identify it. I've edited the code to reflect this.

Comment: Okay the K.I.S.S. principle applies here too much granularity while seemingly nice is not Simple and thus creates far to much unnecessary complexity to the program.  While yes its a good idea to sectionalize your view into top, middle, bottom if applicable it is not a good idea to sub-class all of these elements.  My core MainWindow has 2 sub-classes - CenterPanel and MenuToolBar as those were the 2 smallest elements that made sense functionality wise.

Comment: @nmpauls It's unclear to me why you are using such deep nesting. It makes sense for the underlying *data structure* of the settings to be hierarchical, but I cannot see why you would need to mirror all of that with widgets. Personally, I would just centralise the settings data in a module that can be imported and made globally available wherever it's needed. This module would provide a generic API for reading and writing values that could be used directly by any widget, thus cutting out all the "middle-men". A system like that would probably make a lot of your nesting redundant.

Comment: @DennisJensen Totally makes sense. I'm using subclasses to keep the code readable, but it's definitely not simple. How do you organize your code into something readable without using subclasses? Do you split parts of your app into functions that are called in __init__? I just want my code to still look organized while remaining simple.

Comment: @ekhumoro Yeah, the idea of using a module to manage the data is definitely something I'd like to implement. If you have time, could you explain what globally available means in this context? I'm imagining that the GUI has an instance of a data handling class added as an attribute, and then that instance handles all the data for a given instance of the GUI. Is that kind of what you're thinking?

Comment: @nmpauls The usual way is to create a single instance of the data class as a top-level variable in the module, and then do e.g. `from settings import settings` wherever it is needed. It should not be made an attribute of anything else, because that just re-introduces yet another unnecessary middle-man. Ideally, the contents of the settings module should be pure python with no major dependencies (such as pyqt). This is because access to it is usually required at application startup and shutdown when other modules and objects may not be available.

Comment: @ekhumoro This makes so much sense. I can't believe I didn't think of this myself. Thanks a ton. Do you have any suggestions for flattening out my overall program more? I don't really know how to structure PyQt programs without class hierarchy while also maintaining code readability, but that question is more of a subjective one I suppose.

Comment: @nmpauls As for general structure, I would echo what Dennis Jensen suggested: use the smallest possible number of *functional* components. For a small- to medium-sized PyQt application, this will very often be a single main-window class with just a few custom widget subclasses. A great deal can be achieved with just plain methods, signals-slots, event-handlers and event-filters, with no need for extra classes. This is especially true if you use Qt Designer to create 90% of the GUI.

Comment: @nmpauls PS: there are lots of pyqt example programs [available here](https://github.com/Werkov/PyQt4/tree/master/examples). Most of them are quite simple, but e.g. [the spreadsheet example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtexamplesandtutorials.html) shows what a typical small pyqt program might look like. There's also a tetris game example [here](http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt5/). But beyond basic examples like that, it is very difficult to give general advice, since the overall structure will largely depend on the specific kind of application you are trying to create.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**: The question has been updated in the meantime, I've added a solution that's more specific at the bottom of this answer.

I feel like this question is slightly "opinion based", but since I've had my share of similar situations I'd like to propose my suggestions. In these situations it's important to understand that there's not *one* good way to do things, but *many* ways to do it wrong.

### Original answer

An idea could be to create a common signal interface for every "level", which will get that signal and send it back to its parent by adding its own name to keep track of the setting "path"; the topmost widget will then evaluate the changes accordingly.

In this example every tab "group" has its own `valueChanged` signal, which includes the group name, setting name and value; the source signal is fired from the "source" (a spinbox, in this case), then it follows its parents which, in turn "add" their name in turn.
Keep in mind that you can also just use a generalized `pyqtSignal(object)` for every parent and connect it with `widget.valueChanged.connect(self.valueChanged)`, and then track its group and setting by walking by `self.sender()` parents backwards.

As a final notice, if you are using these values for application *settings*, remember that Qt already provides the [QSettings](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html) API, which can be used as a common and OS-transparent interface for every configuration you need to set (and remember between sessions) in your application. I implemented it in the example, but I suggest you to read its documentation to better understand how it works.

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class SettingWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    valueChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)
    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__()
        self.settings = QtCore.QSettings()
        self.val = 0
        self.name = name
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)
        layout.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel(self.name))
        self.spinBox = QtWidgets.QSpinBox()
        layout.addWidget(self.spinBox)
        self.spinBox.valueChanged.connect(self.set_val)

    def set_val(self, new_val):
        if self.val != new_val:
            self.val = new_val
            self.valueChanged.emit(self.val)
            # enter a setting group, ensuring that same name settings won't
            # be mismatched; this allows a single sub level setting only
            self.settings.beginGroup(self.parent().name)
            self.settings.setValue(self.name, new_val)
            # leave the setting group. THIS IS IMPORTANT!!!
            self.settings.endGroup()

class SettingWidget1(SettingWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('Setting1')

class SettingWidget2(SettingWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('Setting2')

class SettingWidget3(SettingWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('Setting3')

class SettingsGroup(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    # create two signal signatures, the first sends the full "path", 
    # while the last will just send the value
    valueChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal([str, str, int], [int])
    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__()
        self.name = name
        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def add_to_group(self, new_setting):
        widget = new_setting()
        # emit both signal signatures
        widget.valueChanged.connect(
            lambda value, name=widget.name: self.valueChanged.emit(
                self.name, name, value))
        widget.valueChanged.connect(self.valueChanged[int])
        self.layout().addWidget(widget)

class SettingsGroup1(SettingsGroup):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('Group1')
        self.add_to_group(SettingWidget1)
        self.add_to_group(SettingWidget2)

class SettingsGroup2(SettingsGroup):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('Group2')
        self.add_to_group(SettingWidget3)

class TabWidget(QtWidgets.QTabWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QTabWidget.__init__(self)
        self.settings = QtCore.QSettings()
        self.tabs = [SettingsGroup1, SettingsGroup2]
        self.settingsDict = {}
        for tab in self.tabs:
            widget = tab()
            self.addTab(widget, widget.__class__.__name__)
            widget.valueChanged[str, str, int].connect(self.valueChangedFullPath)
            widget.valueChanged[int].connect(self.valueChangedOnly)

    def valueChangedFullPath(self, group, setting, value):
        # update the settings dict; if the group key doesn't exist, create it
        try:
            self.settingsDict[group][setting] = value
        except:
            self.settingsDict[group] = {setting: value}
        settingsData = [group, setting, value]
        print('Full path result: {}'.format(settingsData))
        # Apply setting from here, instead of using the SettingWidget 
        # settings.setValue() option; this allows a single sub level only
        # self.applySetting(data)

    def valueChangedOnly(self, value):
        parent = sender = self.sender()
        # sender() returns the last signal sender, so we need to track down its 
        # source; keep in mind that this is *not* a suggested approach, as 
        # tracking the source might result in recursion if the sender's sender
        # is not one of its children; this system also has issues if you're
        # using a Qt.DirectConnection from a thread different from the one that
        # emitted it
        while parent.sender() in sender.children():
            parent = sender.sender()
        widgetPath = []
        while parent not in self.children():
            widgetPath.insert(0, parent)
            parent = parent.parent()
        settingsData = [w.name for w in widgetPath] + [value]
        print('Single value result: {}'.format(settingsData))
        # similar to valueChangedFullPath(), but with this implementation more 
        # nested "levels" can be used instead
        # self.applySetting(settingsData)

    def applySetting(self, settingsData):
        # walk up to the next to last of settingsData levels, assuming they are
        # all parent group section names
        for count, group in enumerate(settingsData[:-2], 1):
            self.settings.beginGroup(group)
        # set the setting name settingsData[-2] to its value settingsData[-1]
        self.settings.setValue(*settingsData[-2:])
        for g in range(count):
            self.settings.endGroup()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    # set both Organization and Application name to make settings persistent
    app.setOrganizationName('StackOverflow')
    app.setApplicationName('Example')
    w = TabWidget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

### Alternate solution, based on updated question

Since the answer has become more specific in its update, I'm adding another suggestion.
As far as we can understand now, you don't need that level of "nested" classes, but more specifically designed code that can be reused according to your purposes. Also, since you're using binary based data, it makes things a *bit* (pun intended) easier, as long as you know how bit operation works (which I assume you do) and the setting "widgets" don't require specific GUI customization.

In this example I created just *one* "setting" class and *one* "group" class, and their instancies are created only according to their names and default values.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

defaultValues = '0010101', '1001010', '000111'
# set bit lengths for each setting; be careful in ensuring that each
# setting group has the full default value bit length!
groups = [
    ['Group 1', [1, 3, 2, 1]], 
    ['Group 2', [1, 2, 2, 1, 1]], 
    ['Group 1', [2, 1, 2, 1]], 
]

class BinaryWidget(QtWidgets.QFrame):
    changed = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    def __init__(self, name, index, defaults='0'):
        QtWidgets.QFrame.__init__(self)
        self.setFrameShape(self.StyledPanel|self.Sunken)
        layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.index = index
        self.defaults = defaults
        self.buttons = []
        # use the "defaults" length to create buttons
        for i in range(len(defaults)):
            value = int(defaults[i], 2) & 1
            # I used QToolButtons as they're usually smaller than QPushButtons
            btn = QtWidgets.QToolButton()
            btn.setText(str(value))
            layout.addWidget(btn, 1, i)
            btn.setCheckable(True)
            btn.setChecked(value)
            btn.toggled.connect(self.changed)
            # show the binary value on change, just for conveniency
            btn.toggled.connect(lambda v, btn=btn: btn.setText(str(int(v))))
            self.buttons.append(btn)
        layout.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel(name), 0, 0, 1, layout.columnCount())

    def value(self):
        # return the correct value of all widget's buttons; they're reversed
        # because of how bit shifting works
        v = 0
        for i, btn in enumerate(reversed(self.buttons)):
            v += btn.isChecked() << i
        # bit shift again, according to the actual "setting" bit index
        return v << self.index

    def resetValues(self):
        oldValue = self.value()
        self.blockSignals(True)
        for i, value in enumerate(self.defaults):
            self.buttons[i].setChecked(int(self.defaults[i], 2) & 1)
        self.blockSignals(False)
        newValue = self.value()
        # emit the changed signal only once, and only if values actually changed
        if oldValue != newValue:
            self.changed.emit()

class Group(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    changed = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    def __init__(self, name, defaults=None, lenghts=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self)
        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.name = name
        self.bitLength = 0
        self.widgets = []
        if defaults is not None:
            self.addOptions(defaults, lenghts)

    def value(self):
        v = 0
        for widget in self.widgets:
            v += widget.value()
        return v

    def addOption(self, name, index, default='0'):
        widget = BinaryWidget(name, index, default)
        self.layout().addWidget(widget)
        self.widgets.append(widget)
        widget.changed.connect(self.changed)
        self.bitLength += len(default)

    def addOptions(self, defaults, lenghts = None):
        if lenghts is None:
            lenghts = [1] * len(defaults)
        # reverse bit order for per-setting indexing
        defaultsIndex = 0
        bitIndex = len(defaults)
        for i, l in enumerate(lenghts):
            self.addOption(
                'Setting {}'.format(i + 1), 
                bitIndex - l, 
                defaults[defaultsIndex:defaultsIndex + l])
            bitIndex -= l
            defaultsIndex += l

    def resetValues(self):
        for widget in self.widgets:
            widget.resetValues()

class Tester(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self)
        layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget()
        layout.addWidget(self.tabWidget)

        resultLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addLayout(resultLayout, layout.rowCount(), 0, 1, layout.columnCount())

        self.tabs = []
        self.labels = []

        for (group, lenghts), defaults in zip(groups, defaultValues):
            tab = Group(group, defaults, lenghts)
            self.tabWidget.addTab(tab, group)
            tab.changed.connect(self.updateResults)
            self.tabs.append(tab)
            tabLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel()
            self.labels.append(tabLabel)
            resultLayout.addWidget(tabLabel)

        self.resetButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Reset values')
        layout.addWidget(self.resetButton)
        self.resetButton.clicked.connect(lambda: [tab.resetValues() for tab in self.tabs])

        self.updateResults()

    def values(self):
        return [tab.value() for tab in self.tabs]

    def updateResults(self):
        for value, tab, label in zip(self.values(), self.tabs, self.labels):
            label.setText('''
                {0}: <span style="font-family:monospace;">{1} <b>{1:0{2}b}</b></span>
                '''.format(tab.name, value, tab.bitLength))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Tester()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for the response. I think this seems like a pretty reasonable solution given the current structure of my project. I guess some of the discussion around my question has tended towards restructuring my project altogether into something more flat, which I'd like to do. As an experienced PyQt developer, do you have any thoughts on how you normally structure your PyQt apps to accomplish this?

Comment: If you can use designer, it would help you much more: you'd only need a single custom widget class as a base, then eventually create subclasses for each setting, and finally add them to designer as simple QWidgets promoted to those classes; if you want I can update the answer with that solution too. Anyway, it all depends on what your "settings" are designed for and how they would relate to your program (do they change its behavior? do they need to be applied instantly? are they persistent among sessions?); if you give us a deeper insight on that, our suggestions might be more accurate.

Comment: I've updated my question with some more specific info about what the program should generally do. Qt Designer is probably the way to go, and I just started messing around with it this morning actually. Way simpler than I thought it would be. You can definitely update your answer with that.

Comment: @nmpauls I updated the answer accordingly. I didn't understand what you meant with "binary number" (single bit value - as in bool - or bit based values), but I think my update could answer both. For future reference, try to be a bit more specific (but not too much!) in questions, expecially if they tend to be "opinion based" (as in "is there a good/better way to do it?"). Remember that even if spending tens of minutes of your time formulating a *good* answer might seem distressing, it could help you to find solutions on your own, and avoid people to ignore your question as they seem too vague.